# $.each doesn't work with jquery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have DOM like this

```
<div data-id="1" class="box_album_item"></div>
<div data-id="2" class="box_album_item"></div>
<div data-id="3" class="box_album_item"></div>
```

and I uses $.each

```
$.each('.box_album_item',function(i,val){
  console.log($(this).attr('data-id'));
})
```

but I got error of

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in .box_album_item
```

Comment: `$.each` work on arrays not strings if you want to iterate over jquery selector use .each jQuery method `$('.box_album_item').each(function() { ... });`

Comment: It would be: `$.each($('.box_album_item'),function(i,val){...});` but it is recommended to use `$('.box_album_item').each(function() { ... });` even if the second one call internally the first one...

Comment: Why not read [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use it as a jQuery collection's function:

```
$('.box_album_item').each(function(i, val) {
  console.log($(this).attr('data-id'));
});
```

Always please make sure you read the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/each/) and [examples](https://api.jquery.com/each/#entry-examples) before asking.